# Getting an object by its name contained in a string

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, constants

I am trying to get a const object indirectly by its name, which is contained in a string. I have no idea if this is possible but if it is, it would make my life a hell of a lot easier. As an example in pseudocode: `var obj = findObject("myConstObject");`
I know this is a strange thing to need, but I am dealing with quite a large amount of data, and being able to grab objects in this way would work a lot better with my existing code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No remotely good way. A script should not depend on the names its variables have.

Comment: Store the values on keys in an object and index them by their keys: `const o = {}; o["myConstObj"] = {/* data */};`

Comment: what does your source data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` to get all property names of an object. Here is an example that demonstrates how to search a `myObj1` that is in the global `window` scope, and a `myObj2` that is in the `myStuff` object scope:

```js
// object attached to window object:
myObj1 = { a: 1 };

function getKeyNames(aThis) {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(aThis || globalThis).sort();
}

console.log('search myObj1 in global scope:', getKeyNames().filter(name => name === 'myObj1'));

// object attached to my on stuff:
const myStuff = {
    myObj2: { b: 2 },
    deeperLevel: {
      myObj3: { b: 3 },
    }
}

console.log('search myObj2 in myStuff scope:', getKeyNames(myStuff).filter(name => name === 'myObj2'));
```

Output:

```
search myObj1 in global scope: [
  "myObj1"
]
search myObj2 in myStuff scope: [
  "myObj2"
]
```

Notes:

- if needed, expand this code to search recursively the object hierarchy, so that `myStuff.deeperLevel.myObj3` can be found searching `myStuff`
- if needed, expand this code to search a list of objects of interest